# Sensor to sense light in proteus software

Tags: proteus

I'm doing a project in proteus .I'm in need of a light sensor.can anyone say me where it is,or how yo make our own light sensor in proteus.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to sense the presence (or intensity) of light, then you could use a simple LDR (Light Dependent Resistor). You can find one in Transducers or you can find a "LDR and Torch" pair under Miscellaneous as well.

A simple search in Proteus for "LDR" will pull these up for you.